# Looking to connect to my FTP server with a new ISP, Timeout at Initializing TLS

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ftp

Recently moved to a new apartment that has available WIFI. I have been trying to connect to my FTP server through Filezilla. I am not able to connect to it.

**Log from Filezilla**

```
Status: Waiting to retry...
Status: Resolving address of ftp.chirpp.co
Status: Connecting to 192.145.239.17:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
Response:   220-You are user number 11 of 150 allowed.
Response:   220-Local time is now 12:27. Server port: 21.
Response:   220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
Response:   220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
Response:   220 You will be disconnected after 30 minutes of inactivity.
Command:    AUTH TLS
Response:   234 AUTH TLS OK.
Status: Initializing TLS...
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

I have been previously able to connect to my server through my previous internet connection.

EDIT:
**Ran the network configuration test**

```
Connecting to probe.filezilla-project.org
Response: 220 FZ router and firewall tester ready
USER FileZilla
Response: 331 Give any password.
PASS 3.13.1
Response: 230 logged on.
Checking for correct external IP address
Retrieving external IP address from http://ip.filezilla-project.org/ip.php
Checking for correct external IP address
IP 65.121.188.146 gf-bcb-bii-beg
Response: 200 OK
PREP 51845
Response: 200 Using port 51845, data token 1703512949
PORT 65,121,188,146,202,133
Response: 200 PORT command successful
LIST
Response: 150 opening data connection

Response: 503 Failure of data connection.
Server sent unexpected reply.
Connection closed
```

**FileZilla Summary of test results:**
"Summary of test results:

The server sent an unexcepted or unrecognized reply.
This means that some router and/or firewall is still interfering with FileZila."

I have followed the instructions at the bottom of the page for Windows Firewall. https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Network_Configuration. I have Windows 10.

I also tried disabling both my windows firewall and my 360 total security firewall, neither helped!

Comment: Any antivirus that might be blocking the connection? (seems indeed a firewall issue even you being sure it's not...)

Comment: So I've tried to turn off any personal antivirus. But I don't think a personal firewall would be a problem since I have been able to connect before just through a different network. My thought is that it could be a firewall on the router. Could that be my source of problems?

Anyway I can test the case/ isolate where the problem is stemming from?

Comment: Configure your Filezilla to use **passive FTP mode** and try to connect.

Comment: Tried both active/ passive. Both don't connect.

Comment: This guy [here](https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=19172) had exactly the same problem and his solution was to disable firewall.

Comment: Speak with your ISP, they may be blocking it.

Comment: I think your router firewall is a good candidate to be the culprit. Usually when some error happens the answer is very short, but in your case it's taking 20 secs. to timeout. When using passive mode, there's a pool of additional (usually) high number ports which are used so the passive connection is established. However, if you say you tried the active mode as well and still times out, it's odd...

Comment: I believe my ISP is century link. The router is from http://rgnets.com/. Would it be a good idea to call century link and let them know I cannot connect to my FTP server?

I contacted rgnets and they said their router doesn't do any blocking out of the box.

Comment: **Passive or active mode are not relevant here.** This happens before any data connections. It’s about the control connection. @MichaelPetrochuk Are you living in a country where encryption is discouraged/outlawed?

Comment: @danielB I am living the USA. I don't think so!

Answer (score -1):

did you manage to sort this?
I had a similar issue... turned out to be a 3rd party protection software in my ASUS router preventing connection.
Turned it off, defaulted everything, worked fine...brought my settings back in after to make sure. Drove me nuts!

Comment: Nope! I still have this problem. I've contacted just about everyone I could and after a year they have not figured it out.... :/